# Word game algorithm

Tags: algorithms, language-agnostic

Back in the days of 8-bit machines there existed an educational word game. I have no idea what it was actually called but for the sake of this question (since it involves pyramids) let's call it **Stones of Giza**.

The game was simple. Starting at the top level, a letter was added to a single letter word and another word was formed. A letter was then added to that word and so on down, each time making a word. The levels went from 3 to 7.

An example of level 3 might be.

```
  A
 A T
B A T

Letters: AAABTT
```

Like the 80s game [mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)), you scored for guessing a letter at a level correctly but more for guessing the *position* correctly.

It isn't hard to see that the only candidates for the top stone are A, I and O - since these are the only single letter words in the English language.

My question is around algorithms for sourcing game boards. My brute force algorithm currently searches for length *N* words with one of the 3 letters above and then checks the N-1 length word on the left/right hand side containing the pinnacle letter (A, I or O).

This strikes me as slightly inefficient since there are going to be many false searches.

How can I improve on this raw algorithm? Higher levels are taking quite a long time on a good sized dictionary.

I do of course realise that the 8-bit game probably wasn't parsing the data each time and had a set number of boards but I'm just trying to optimise creating the source data out of curiosity.

**EDIT #1:**

I have already filtered out words in the source dictionary that don't contain A, I or O.

Comment: `It isn't hard to see that the only candidates for the top stone are A, I and O` -- It is for me.  Why are the only candidates for the top stone A, I and O?

Comment: Each level has to form a word.

Comment: How about H? ...

Comment: H isn't a word...

Comment: But Bath is. So is Hat, and Ah.  Your algorithm seems underspecified.

Comment: H cannot sit at the top of the tree since it isn't a single letter word...

Comment: Neither is O....?  Perhaps you mean [this ancient version of O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case#English).

Comment: Slightly contentious but is oft used in poetry and rhyme...

Comment: If it greases the wheels, just consider A and I...

Comment: O Romeo, Romeo... Anyway, for an actual game I'd probably pre-calculate the word DAG in its entirety. Then I'd store just the edges of the graph, labelling them `(L,i)`, where `L` is the letter being added to the previous word, and `i` the position where the letter goes.

Comment: What kind of efficiency are you looking for?  Time?  Space?

Comment: @Blrfl It is taking too long so I'm guessing the algorithm and/or source dictionary could be optimised.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to (ab)use maps and sets (or lists).

You have a map with "current word" as key and "list or set of successor words" as value.

You can then populate your map using something like the following:

```
for word in dictionary:
  for 0 <= position < length(word):
    key = drop_letter(word, position) ## drop_letter("bath", 3) -> bat
    successors[key].append(word)
```

Of course, this would possibly require a bit more coding to take it from pseudo-code to working code.

Then you have your possible starting positions in `successors[""]` and can continue to simply pick a successor from there. If the game allows arbitrary re-arrangement of letters from one row to the next (so that "bath" is a valid successor to "tab") sort the key before using it (so the keys from "bath" would be "aht", "bht", "abh" and "abt").

Generating the initial list is amortised O(n*m) for "n words, of length max m", look-up during the game should be relatively fast.

If you do this off-line and store it in a data file, you may also be able to filter out "non-word" keys, lessening the amount of data needed in RAM.

Comment: If letters can't be rearranged, it's probably more efficient to only store the new letter and its position rather than the entire successor word.

Comment: More space-efficient, for sure (you're trading an M-character string for a single character and a small-ish integer)